# How to provide a given symbol using Clang and MacOSX

Tags: c++, macos, clang

I have an issue when launching my application:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN5mongo2LTE
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libcrails-mongodb.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/libcrails-mongodb.dylib
```

If I search for the symbol `__ZN5mongo2LTE` using nm, I find these matches:

```
$: nm -A /usr/local/lib/libcrails-mongodb.dylib | grep __ZN5mongo2LTE
/usr/local/lib/libcrails-mongodb.dylib:                  U __ZN5mongo2LTE
```

If my understanding is correct, this means that the symbol is referenced, but not solved.

Now if I look at this other library that is also linked to my project:

```
$: nm -A /usr/lib/libmongoclient.a | grep __ZN5mongo2LTE
/usr/lib/libmongoclient.a:jsobj.o: 00000000000eca00 S __ZN5mongo2LTE
```

Again, in my understanding, this means the symbol exists in this same library at the given address.

Am I wrong somewhere ? If not, then why is the symbol "not found" ?

Comment: Why are you linking both the static and dynamic versions of the same library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems an accessible `libmongoclient.dylib` or `libmongoclient.so` required. 
the `libcrails-mongodb.dylib` is linked **dynamically** with `libmongoclient`, thus it can not find the symbol, though there's static `libmongoclient.a`. 
You may try to recompile `libcrails-mongodb` statically with `libmongoclient.a`, or find a dynamic library of `libmongoclient`, typically `libmongoclient.dylib` or `libmongoclient.so`.

Comment: I haven't fixed the problem yet, but that makes perfect sense and I'm marking this as valid right now :D ! Thanks for the help !